# Powershell remote script execution issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to execute a powershell script from the host 1.2.3.3 on the box 1.2.3.4 remotely

```
$cred = get-credential 
$process = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class WHERE __Class = 'Win32_Process'" -namespace "root\cimv2" -computername 1.2.3.4 -credential $cred 
$results = $process.Create("powershell.exe /c C:\Windows\temp\hello.ps1 arg1")
```

I can see the process getting created (as the return value says 0) but the process is dies down immediately in the remote system(1.2.3.4)

> I tried powershell.exe -file option also instead of powershell.exe /c

I tried using Invoke-Command but that dosent work because of trusted hosts issue.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell.exe parameters starts with a dash (e.g '-'), for full help type: PowerShell.exe /?.

What do you expect to happen? What the script is doing? Should it "die" this way?

Comment: I was trying to install an exeutable. In the powershell script i will access the exe from a shared location and install it. Also i tried -file option instead of /c and that also didnt work either

Comment: The exit code you get is the exit code of the new created process, not the exit code of installation process

Comment: I am referring to the exit code when printing the variable $results  

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ProcessId        : 6336
ReturnValue      : 0

Comment: Exactly, you get the return value that the creation succeeded, not the exit code of the PowerShell process.

Comment: Check this post http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2008/05/20/hey-powershell-guy-how-can-i-run-a-powershell-script-from-cmd-exe-and-return-an-errorlevel.aspx

Comment: Then what i understood is wrong...Then why dont i see the installation starting the remote machine? what i am missing here?

Comment: I would start by making sure that the script can access the shared location. Try to log errors to a local file and see if you can find acess issues